# The cast can never be succeed

Tags: oop, casting, kotlin

I am new in Kotlin and I currently study about the concept of OOP

I am trying to do a cast with this code, but I'm facing an error:

```kotlin
    open class Operations1(){
        open  fun sum(n1:Int , n2:Int):Int{
            return n1+ n2
        }
        fun sub(n1:Int , n2:Int):Int{
            return n1- n2
        }
    }
    class multiOperations1():Operations(){
        override  fun sum(n1:Int , n2:Int):Int{
            return n1+ n2 +5
        }
        fun mul(n1:Int , n2:Int):Int{
            return n1* n2
        }
        fun div(n1:Int , n2:Int):Int{
            return n1/ n2
        }
    }
    fun main(args:Array<String>){

        var oper = Operations()
        var inlit  = multiOperations1() as Operations1
        println("Enter first number")
        var n1:Int = readLine()!!.toInt()
        println("Enter Second Number")
        var n2:Int = readLine()!!.toInt()

        var sum = inlit.sum(n1 , n2)
        var sub = inlit.sub(n1 , n2)
        println("Sum: " + sum)
        println("Sub: " + sub)
    }
```

Screen shot of the code

[image: This is the screen shot of the code]

error:

[image: This is the error which my program through]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve you can use Gson and avoid boilerplate code.

```
var operation= Operations(....)

val json = Gson().toJson(operation)

val multiOperations:MultiOperations =Gson().fromJson(json, MultiOperations::class.java)
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have both an `Operations` and an `Operations1` class. Your `multiOperations1` class inherits from `Operations` instead of `Operations1`, so you won't be able to cast it to `Operations1` (unless `Operations` is a subclass of `Operations1`).

I assume you wanted to inherit from Operations1 instead, like this:

```
class multiOperations1(): Operations1() {
    ...
}
```

A note on conventions: class names in Kotlin usually follow Java conventions, and use upper camel case, so you should probably name your class `MultiOperations1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use -

```
 var inlit  = multiOperations1() as Operations
```

You can typecast your derived class to parent class. In your case `multiOperations1` class have a parent class `Operations`.

Just a suggestion start you class name like `multiOperations1` from capital letter.